# How can I change the web-service URL in a BDC model

Tags: 2010, bdc-model

In SharePoint 2010, I have a BDC connection created by importing a BDC model file via central admin. However, the machine providing the web-service has changed and I need to update the BDC model's properties to reflect this. (In particular, the WSDL's URL has changed).

How can I do this? If I attempt to simply upload an updated .bdcm file I get the error:

```
Application definition import failed. The following error occurred: Cannot merge contents of LobSystem (External System) with Name 'TrainingService' as it appears to be different from a preexisting LobSystem in the current load context. Error was encountered at or just before Line: '13' and Position: '8'.
```

I am considering using Import-SPBusinessDataCatalogModel with the -Force parameter, but am worried that my existing lists based upon the external content type will break. Will this happen?

What is the correct approach for updating deployed BDC models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ha-Latn-NG/sharepoint2010setup/thread/801586ef-ddf4-4dd7-a562-0126af291beb

Simply deleting the old BDC model and importing the modified version worked.

Comment: What's about using Catalog, not Model ? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/109706/removing-a-bdc-catalog-using-powershell

Answer (score 0):

Did you update the version numbers? Go through your file and increase all "Version" tags by one (the last number, the format is 1.n.n.n)

Comment: I tried this. It didn't solve the problem.